# Inserting a range from Excel to Word as caps

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have VBA set up to insert data from Excel cells to bookmarks on a Word document - is there any way that I can insert as caps rather than as it is set up in Excel? I've tried selecting the range and then `selection.Range.Case` but to no avail.

```
Sub Test()

Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim objRange

r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5 To r
    With Cells(i, 5)
        If .Value = "TTRO" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
            Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

            objWord.Visible = True
            Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(Template:="S:\.....", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

            Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("LicenceNo").Range
            objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 4)

            Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Date").Range
            objRange.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="d/M/yyyy"

            Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Company").Range
            objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 7)

            Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Address").Range
            objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 8)

            Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Location").Range
            objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 13)

            Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Location2").Range
            objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 12)

            Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("From").Range
            objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 18)

            Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("To").Range
            objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 19)

            Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Date2").Range
            objRange.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="d/M/yyyy"
        End If
End With

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies, that is actually in there, there's a whole lot of other code I took out just so this was easier to look at. I'll amend.

Comment: Add a UCase around `Cells(`, like `objRange.InsertAfter UCase(Cells(i, 8))`

Comment: Outstanding, thank you!

Comment: Another thing that's now come up - is there any way to insert a date as text? The code `Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("From").Range
            objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 18)` contains a date in the cell in row 18, could this be inserted as text despite it being shown as an actual date on the spreadsheet?

Comment: Is there any way to write the whole date as text? Eg seventeenth may?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but here is some advice on how to use Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Supplementing Sam's response: The site concept is Q&A. That means one issue / question. Ask your completely new issue in a new question. But I recommend, for this particular problem, to research formatting dates and the `Format` function in VBA. As you can imagine, this kind of thing comes up fairly regularly, so I think you can find what you're looking for without a new question...